# Retrieving selected items from DIV - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to fetch data from database and append to my `panel` as in my code. But the problem is on page load for instance,

Answer (score 2):

I see your `Function` changes values of `sum` and `total_points` variables, but I cant see where you use them. Also I dont see any point of doing:

```
   $(".line-total").each(function(){
   sum = sum + quantity*price;
   })   


   $(".pts-total").each(function(){
   total_points = total_points + quantity*points;
   })
```

Because when you execute it - `Function()`, it just changes values of `sum` and `total_points` many times. Same like:

```
var foo = 1;
(function() {
  foo = 2;
  foo = 3;
  foo = 4;
})();
```

So it just returns `foo` with value of 4 and `foo = 2;` and `foo = 3;` doesn't seem to be used. So if your `total_points` sets value of `sub-total` from your table, it makes sense that it might return same values as many times you call `Function`

Comment: i am actually trying to multiply the quantity and price for each line to get the sub-total. that is what i am trying to acheive

Comment: I am not familiar with a way you initialise DOM elements, but what you can do is console.log values of these variables on every loop - For ex. after grab value - `var quantity = Number($('.quantity').val());` do - `console.log(quantity)`. because `$('.quantity')` creates an array of DOM items collection with the `.quantity` class

Answer (score 0):

This is simple Jquery code which can help you in your question.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){

var qty=$("#qty").val();
var rate=$("#rate").val();


var total=(qty*rate)

$("#tbody").append("<tr><td>"+qty+"</td><td>"+rate+"</td><td>"+total+"</td></tr>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="qty" type="text" placeholder="quantity"/><br>
<input id="rate" type="text" placeholder="Rate"/><br>

<input id="btn" type="button" value="enter"/><br>

<table>
<tbody id="tbody">
<tr>
<td>quantity</td>
<td>rate</td>
<td>total</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>

</script>
```